# Error opening the page after the Publish web site. Error : The controller for path '/MessageBox' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After the changes made to the program after adding a new page (Controller)
My application runs in the local system
But When Publish project and copy to the server The same page will not open.

My Error Log by Elmah:

```
    <error errorId="676f3cec-b1cc-4c1b-8293-ccbee5cd3bd1" 
application="/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT" host="WIN-RBJDVFHFD14" 
type="System.Web.HttpException"
 message="The controller for path '/MessageBox' was not found or does not implement IController." 
 source="System.Web.Mvc" 
 detail="System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/MessageBox' was not found or does not implement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Controller Name is : MessageBox
This name can not be selected when use IIS